# Modyfing Android applications and licensing

Tags: android, licensing

Code for default sms/mms app is available open. Can I modify this app (I had to extend some functionality) and both make ads support version and paid one with no ads. Is it against licence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want something which is against licence, In my opinion you shouldn't do that. Mostly you can get alternate examples and open source code, just try Google.

**-EDITED-**

The link you have provided has a Notice file which has licence terms, below is the portion from that file

```
Redistribution. You may reproduce and distribute copies of the
      Work or Derivative Works thereof in any medium, with or without
      modifications, and in Source or Object form, provided that You
      meet the following conditions:
```

I think you can modify code but you have to fulfill certain conditions, see complete detail here

https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_mms/blob/master/NOTICE

Comment: Point is I don't know if it is against license

Comment: can u post the link for default sms/mms app

Comment: https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_mms